# Object into Components

Tags: react-native

Hello i have a object and i want to know if its possible to render components based on it. My current object is:

I cant post images yet so here's the link to my structure

[myobject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPtI2.jpg)

I tried the map function but didn't work

What i want is to display  Text components with  the words

> vdks
>   wisk

and any other words in the same scope. Thanks for your help

Comment: You should include your data structure as code in your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @FlorianCargoet My data is in firebase database, How can i put it here, Thanks and sorry im a newbie here

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over an object, you can use `Object.keys()`. It returns an array with all the keys in the object. Here, `Object.keys(myobject)` will return `["vdks", "wisks"]`;

```
<View>
  {Object.keys(myobject).map(key => {
    return <Text>{key}</Text>;
  })}
</View>
```

You can access each nested object with `myobject[key]`;